# How to merge two files with different lengths and columns linux

Tags: awk, files, merge

I have 2 files with different columns and length and I want to merge them as desired output file given below, Please Help!!!

**File 1**

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

**File 2**

```
ff , 2 , tg12
dd , 3 , tg13
gg , 4 , tg14
hh , 5 , tg15
aa , 6 , tg16
bb , 7 , tg17
cc , 8 , tg18
ii , 9 , tg19
```

**Desired output**

```
aa , 6 , tg16
bb , 7 , tg17
cc , 8 , tg18
dd , 3 , tg13
```

Comment: format your question to make it readable

Comment: @steeldriver can you suggest how can I do that?

Comment: @Amber, is the order of lines by "starting field" matters?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes the order of line matters

Answer (score 1):

**`AWK`** solution (ordered by **`sort`** command):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }$1 in a' file1 FS='[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]' file2 | sort
```

- `FS='[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]'` - field separator that is set for `file2`

---

The output:

```
aa , 6 , tg16
bb , 7 , tg17
cc , 8 , tg18
dd , 3 , tg13
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I could think of:

```
grep -f file1 file2 | sort
```